# B760 GAMING X AX DDR4 VGA led is constantly on (HDMI not working)

Tags: hdmi, vga

I completed my new PC - everything works fine... USBs are charging,fans spinning, but the  CPU and RAM LED blinks but the LED stays on the VGA ..

What could be the issue? Not internal graphic port (HDMI) not external (Gainward Ghost GeForce RTX 3060 12GB) does not send any video out of the HDMI port ...

Any idea what's wrong?

Here is the list of all components: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/HzMHDZ

[image: pic]

[image: fullBoard]

SOLVED:
Bios flash (QFLASH_PLUS) did the trick ... with the latest version F9

Comment: What does the manual say about the LED in question? Is all DDR4 being detected?

Comment: Manual says `Status LEDs
The status LEDs show whether the CPU, memory, graphics card, and operating system are working properly
after system power-on. If the CPU/DRAM/VGA LED is on, that means the corresponding device is not working
normally; if the BOOT LED is on, that means you haven't entered the operating system yet.` and `CPU: CPU status LED
DRAM: Memory status LED
VGA: Graphics card status LED
BOOT: Operating system status LED` ... that's all :(  link: https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_b760-gx-series_1301_e.pdf?v=2f911e9c19646ca317e333780e0251fc (p. 20)

Comment: I can't tell from the image is the DRAM LED or VGA LED turned on?

Comment: check the first image ... it's VGA LED - CPU and DRAM is fine..

Comment: I did check the first image. I cannot read the text in the image.  Have you tried to install the GPU in a different PCIe slot?

Comment: I can only fit it in the top one (out of the two at the bottom) because the case sux (pls don't ask me why :D it was ordered by my sister-in-law .... ) .. the case is fucked but when I plug in the graphic card... the fans are spinning, the logo is lit... so I would assume it would be working .... but the VGA LED stays the same and no HDMI is working :(

Comment: one thing I was thinking about is .. in the pcpartpicker (component list) it says the BIOS needs to be updated to at least v8 .... I haven't tried that yet, but I might use updating it via Q-Flesh and USB... tho, again, I have never done that before so I hope I won't mess up.. that's the only thing I can think of could be of an  issue... tho, it's said that it's CPU related.. not VGA (but who knows)

Comment: The notification states, the firmware update, is required if you have a Intel Core i7-14700F. If the system boots then you are already at that firmware level. I would try moving the SSD to a different slot M.2 PCIe and PCIe slots often share the same bandwidth.  I would check the manual to determine which slots are Independant from one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to flash the BIOS to the latest version via USB and QFLASH_PLUS ..